# how to update ios to a specific version

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

During our App test, we need to make sure our App works well on most iOS versions. And is there a way to update iOS version of iPhone to a specific version?

Comment: It's silly that this was closed. Of course it's a real question, and it presents a real problem that iOS developers face. You can't (at least not easily...) upgrade a device to a *specific* version of iOS. All you can do is upgrade to the *latest* version.

Here's a link to how to [do it in iTunes](http://osxdaily.com/2013/09/18/how-to-install-upgrade-ios-7-manually-with-ipsw/)

Comment: And here's [a link to do it for iOS8](http://osxdaily.com/2014/09/17/ios-8-ipsw-download/) (shmim's link provides iOS7 downloads and instructions).

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade an iPhone to a newer version, but beware, you cannot then change back to a lower version of iOS. i.e. Once a phone is on iOS 5.1, you cannot then change it back to iOS 5.0.

To do the upgrade, you use the Organiser window in XCode. Select the "Devices" tab, and you will see the option to change the iOS version for that device.

Apple recommends (as do I) that you have separate devices for each iOS version you wish to test on. Therefore, one iPhone per version. Then you can easily test your code on all the different versions of iOS.

See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/install_ios.html)

Especially this note:

> Important The version of iOS you install must be the same as or newer than the version currently installed on the device. Attempting to install an older software image will fail. After a failed installation attempt, you must reinstall the last successfully installed version or a newer version of iOS.

Comment: So they want developers to buy multiple devices for testing.. that's **so** Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in iTunes you can upload firmware that you've downloaded. I used to use http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/ to get the link to the firmware hosted by apple I wanted when I was jailbreaking. When you plug in the device, you should get a screen that allows you to check or install updates, and if you shift-click on it, you can select a file.

Note: I'm doing this from memory from about a year ago, but if I'm not precisely correct, I believe I still have the right idea and path forward.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited knowledge, no there's no way you could do this unless you have iphone/ipad with the iOS version you want to test.

I should stress it there appears no way to do this in a legit way that will leave the phone intact for testing IAP and etc.

Hope someone proves me wrong on this.